# I can't figure out what's wrong with the python code below. It keeps giving me Attribute error: 'Dog' object has no attribute '_Dog_name'

Tags: attributes

```
class Animal:
     __name = None
     __height = 0
     __weight = 0
     __sound = 0
```

## We call a constructor, a constructor is called to setup/initialize an object

```
    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
        self.__name = name
        self.__height = height
        self.__weight = weight
        self.__sound = sound

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def set_height(self, height):
        self.__height = height

    def get_height(self, height):
        return self.__height

    def set_weight(self, weight):
        self.__weight = weight

    def get_weight(self):
        return self.__weight

    def set_sound(self, sound):
        self.__sound = sound

    def get_sound(self):
        return self.__sound

    def get_type(self):
        print("Animal")

    def toString(self):
        return "{} is {} cm tall and {} kilograms in weight and makes the       sound {}".format(self.__name, self.__height,
                                                                                       self.__weight, self.__sound)


cat = Animal('Whiskers', 33, 20, 'meow')
print(cat.get_name())
print(cat.toString())



class Dog(Animal):

    __owner= ""

    def __init__(self,name,height,weight,sound,owner):
        self.__owner=owner
        super(Dog,self).__init__(name,height,weight,sound)

    def set_owner(self,owner):
        self.__owner=owner

    def get_owner(self):
        return self.__owner

    def get_type(self):
        print("dog")

    def toString(self):
        return"{} is {} cm tall and weighs {}. He says {} and his owner is {}".format(self.__name,
                                                                                      self.__height,
                                                                                      self.__weight,
                                                                                      self.__sound,
                                                                                      self.__owner)

Spot = Dog("Spot",45,77,"Ruff","Amit")
print(Spot.toString())
```

Here the class Animal is being called in to use its attributes. I saw this on a tutorial video, it seems to be running fine in the video but not when I try it

Comment: You're going to have to explain what the Animal class is

Comment: I have before this piece of code and it worked fine giving me the output I needed. I just didn't paste it because it would then become too long a code to go through

Comment: Without seeing the Animal class I can't tell you what's wrong with this code because I don't even see the _Dog_name attribute in this class

Comment: Okay I have added the class Animals

Comment: Did the answer satisfy your question?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with "name mangling" (c.f. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references). If you wish to access super class variables with double underscores, you should prefix them with the class name:

```
def toString(self):
    return"{} is {} cm tall and weighs {}. He says {} and his owner is {}".\
        format(self._Animal__name,
               self._Animal__height,
               self._Animal__weight,
               self._Animal__sound,
               self.__owner)
```

Alternatively you could call the getters from `Animal` such as `self.get_name()`.